# Return from Jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery

I have the following extremely basic $.ajax function:

```
function doAjax(url, args){
    var retVal = $.ajax({  
                    type:   "GET",
                    url:    url,
                    data:   args,
                    async:  false
                 }).responseText;
    return retVal;
}
```

When processed, the returned data from the url should be some text, like "Invalid User credentials".

What is actually being returned by retVal some preformatted HTML, specifically:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <h1>SRV Server:</h1><br> Document Contains no data. 
   </body>
</html>
```

I am not understanding why. Can anyone explain what is going on with this script?

The server side code is accepting and processing the data correctly. This is the code that the $.ajax calls, it validates the args and processes the data accordingly.

The return from the '$retval = $fvAPI->responseCurl['ERROR'];' statement is: "Invalid User credentials".

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/freightView.inc.php';
$id     = 0;
$fv     = 0;
$status = 0;
$retval = null;
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
     $id=$_GET['id'];
    if(is_numeric($id)){
        if(isset($_GET['fv']) && strlen($_GET['fv'])>3){
            $fv1 = substr($_GET['fv'],4,1);
            if(is_numeric($fv1)&& $fv1>0){
                $fv=$fv1;
                $status=1;
            }
            else $status = 0;
        }
        else $status = 0;
    }
    else $status = 0;
}
else $status = 0;
if($status==1){
    $fvAPI = new fv($id);
    switch ($fv){
        case 1:
            if($fvAPI->postEditXML()){
                $retval = $fvAPI->responseCurl['ERROR'];
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3: 
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        defaut:
            break;
    }
}
return $retval;
```

Comment: What is the content of 'args'?  It seems obvious that you're not sending the proper data, and the remote server is rejecting your request.

Comment: Paste the URL you're using into a browser's address bar.

Comment: what is you server side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery is working but the server is returning an error for that request. If you put the url into a browser you will see the same result.

You need to identify why the server is responding with an error.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. As always, this forum is the best on the net! The issue is with the browser or some settings as you say. At least now I can go that route to identify the root cause. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you hit the URL directly (with args?) If you have firebug, open up the console tab, right-click on the request and click "Open in new tab."

From here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Document_contains_no_data

Mozilla is having a problem loading the page, so I suspect your AJAX is fine but your server is not configured properly. Loading the URL in a non-AJAX fashion will let us find out!

Comment: Jonathon, you are absolutely correct. Putting the URL and args in directly results in the page loading as I defined above.

Comment: Working on it. I use the NuSphere IDE and this is being run on a local server. So far, I have not found the reason why it is returning the reported server status text but I will get it. You pointed me in the right direction, and learned something new. I will report what I find when resolved.